# Occasional Windows stutters/slowdowns

Tags: windows, audio, performance

Ever few hours, my computer suddenly stutters. By this I mean: any audio slows down and sounds sort of robotic as if it's replaying the same buffer repeatedly, and simultaneously the mouse travels slowly. It lasts for approximately a second or two. This can happen when I'm idle at the desktop on a fresh boot, with no other software running, or when doing typical productivity work/programming. However curiously I haven't noticed it ever happen while playing a game. It doesn't seem to be correlated to high CPU tasks - happens just as much at ~idle as it does while compiling C++.

My PC is a Ryzen 3800X, 32GB RAM, B450 Tomahawk Max, RTX 2070 Super, Windows 10 Pro (all up to date with Windows Defender enabled) and boot drive is a 970 Pro 512GB NVMe with Bitlocker, wired ethernet, Ryzen High Performance power plan. All at stock speeds except for PBO enabled. It has never crashed or otherwise malfunctioned.

This has happened every since I built the computer in February. It's not the worst thing in the world, but it is rather annoying. I have a similar PC build at work - except Ryzen 3900X - and it has no such problems.

I have tried:

- Unplugging all non-essential peripherals and using a wired mouse/keyboard
- Disabling all background services
- Turning off virtualisation in the BIOS
- Running [LatencyMon](https://www.resplendence.com/latencymon) - it doesn't seem to show anything out of the ordinary when a stutter occurs.
- Looking in event viewer, nothing obvious to report
- Didn't see anything obvious in task manager when it happens

Any suggestions for how to debug this issue further? Thanks

Comment: Can you try opening Power Management and set it to High Performance? If you don't see this scheme, choose: Create new Power scheme on the left, select the High Performance template and name it High Performance, then switch to it and see if the problem is gone?

Comment: @LPChip My power management is set to Ryzen High Performance

Comment: I noticed, I'm not sure what it does compared to the Windows default High Performance, but I know that if its not on Windows High Performance, it may sometimes give weird slow down issues. So to test, my question was to set it to the windows High Performance setting with default values just to test if this is working or not.